# How to use special characters in SQL Server variables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

I'm trying to declare a variable like `@wi-fi` in SQL Server but dash character in not allowed. There are other characters like `/ * - ( )` with same problem. I know for table or column name we can put it in the `[]` but what about declaring variables? is there a solution?

I have already searched the web but couldn't find any way.

Comment: Why do you insist on using special characters?

Comment: because i have to.

Comment: What version? and can you provide what you tried so far?

Comment: What do you have to?

Comment: You should describe your reasons for needing this better, then people might be able to offer alternative solutions.

Answer (score 14):

Local variable names must comply with the rules for identifiers. MSDN says that :

> When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets.

But this rule is not valid for variables naming. In SQL Server there is a restriction on variable names. All variable names must begin with a single `@` sign. After that the variable name must follow the rules for identifiers and can contain a total of 128 characters.When we say characters, we mean that the name can contain `letters, numbers, the @ sign, the pound sign, the dollar sign and the underscore character`. **The variable name can not contain any dash or spaces**.

[READ MORE HERE](https://books.google.com/books?id=1UknCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA354&lpg=PA354&dq=variable%20name%20contains%20dash%20tsql&source=bl&ots=O1XPvjC2dv&sig=UsbGWpQQA4shYW6NdSgGwi65P1w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY0a--ybHNAhXEExoKHRTZCgcQ6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=variable%20name%20contains%20dash%20tsql&f=false)

Comment: To clarify - "the pound sign" here is the American usage of the term, referring to the `#` character, and not `£`.

Answer (score 0):

Some context to answer people such as @Alex who need to know the "why" for questions like this:

I ran into a similar problem, I needed to use just a small piece of a URL saved in my db where the front and ends were irrelevant.

I first attempted to use:

```
declare @variable varchar(250) = %x%; 
SELECT * FROM tblone WHERE column1 LIKE '@variable'
```

however this returned error: `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar`

My working query was formatted:

```
declare @variable varchar(1000) = x; 
SELECT * FROM tblone WHERE column1 LIKE '%'+@variable+'%'
```